# bottom padding on scrolling fixed-height div is ignored in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a div with a fixed height and a padding attribute. I set `overflow` to `auto` to let the browser add scrollbars. I want to be able to scroll down until the whole bottom padding is visible, but it gets truncated entirely.

[image]

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZR9k5/1/)

CSS:

```
#content {
    padding: 40px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

**Edit: I found out that it only misbehaves on Firefox (29.0.1 for me)**

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748518

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use margins instead of padding, wrap your text in paragraph tags and change your width to accomodate for the difference. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZR9k5/3/)

```
#content, #content2 {
   width: 330px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   overflow: auto;
}

#content {
   height: 200px;
   float:left;
}
p {
   margin: 40px;
}
```